# keep showing a hidden div on refresh page

Tags: jquery

So I have several hidden divs, let say:

```
<div id="1">
  this is div 1
  <a class="btn" href="#2">Next</p>
</div>
<div id="2">
  this is div 2
  <a class="btn" href="#3">Next</p>
</div>
<div id="3">
  this is div 3
  <a class="btn" href="#1">Next</p>
</div>
```

By default, div1 will display and div2 and 3 will be hidden. If I click on the anchor, it will append a div id to the url and show that div. For instance, app/page#2 will display div2. The problem I have is when I refresh the page with the example url, div1 will display instead of div2. I think I can solve this problem by writing jquery function to modify the url and whatever div after the page will be display. However, I think jquery will support an easier way to handle this problem. Would anyone mind to confirm my thinking? Thank you

Comment: Is not this the role of cookies?

Comment: Use session or cookies . [session tutorial](http://code.ciphertrick.com/2015/01/20/session-handling-using-jquery/)

Comment: you can also control browser state and history with javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
$('#1').hide();
$('#'+hash).show();
```

Should work I guess